# cannot telnet remote hadoop server port 9000

Tags: linux, telnet, firewall, hadoop2

I installed a `SUSE VM` remotely. It's IP Address is `16.157.134.132`. 
Then,I installed `Hadoop Server` on it with pseudo distribution. 
After I start `-dfs.sh`, everything is fine. Both `amenode` and `datanode` can become active.

However, when I try to use `eclipse-hadoop` plugin which need to access server port `9000` in my local PC which it's IP is `192.168.199.196`, I get connection exception error. 
Then, I tried `telnet 16.157.134.132 9000` from my local PC, and get following errors:

```
Connecting To 16.157.134.132...Could not open connection to the host,
on port 9000.: Connect failed
```

But I can `telnet 16.157.134.132 50070` successfully which is also used by `Hadoop Server`.

Then I check the `nestat` in sever; here is the two port main difference:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25543/java   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25543/java
```

As you can see, the `9000` will only listens to local requests. but `50070` can listen to all requests. 
There is no firewall on the server and when I `telnet` both `9000` and `50070` from server itself:

```
linux-xlwu:/home/BoboXu # telnet localhost 9000 Trying ::1... telnet:
connect to address ::1: Connection refused Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'.


linux-xlwu:/home/BoboXu # telnet localhost 50070
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

This issue has remained for more than 1 week and I cannot fix it.

My Server system is `SUSE`, and local PC is `win7`.

Please somebody give me a solution.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: `127.0.0.1:9000` - That is the loopback interface that port 9000 is bound to

Comment: You should configure your system to listening 0.0.0.0:9000 or <your_public_ip>:9000, not 127.0.0.1:9000. So after than you'll be able connect via telnet @ <ip>:9000